# Spring Batch - Handle Stored Procedure read failure for bulk data

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to handle an error scenario in Spring batch and want to understand the best way around.

Problem statement: Reading the data using StoredProcedureReader for a range of data set. For example - select * from TABLE where ID between 1 to 100 and status='UNPROCESSED';

In case if there is some issue with the 1 data record, say invalid character that cannot be parsed by DB for record with ID 25, the whole query fails and all 100 records will be missed to get processed.

I want these 100 records to be marked and processed one by one. Is it possible to do it through a listener? What is the best way to handle this?